# Spring nested transaction marked as rollbackonly with unchecked exception

Tags: spring, hibernate, transactions

I am fairly new to Spring and transactions. I am sure this question has been asked before, but I still cannot figure the correct way to go about it.

I am using Spring and hibernate. I have a service method that goes like this:

```
@Transactional
public void processPendingReport(Report report) {
  try {
    // Do processing stuff, update report object state
    reportDAO.save(report);
  } catch (Exception e) {
    reportDAO.markReportAsFailed(report);
  }
}
```

If a RuntimeException occurs during processing, a "Transaction marked as rollbackOnly" RollbackException will be thrown, having as a result that the report will not be marked as failed (although I would like it to be).

I have tried using @Transactional(noRollbackFor=Exception.class), but still get the same issue.. Any suggestions? Could it be a configuration issue?

Comment: Is the reportDAO class also marked @Transactional?

Comment: what is transaction propagation used for reportDAO.save and reportDAO.markReportAsFailed?

Comment: The reportDAO is marked as @Transactional at the class level. There is no explixit tx:advice declaration in the applicationContext.xml, so it should be the default, REQUIRED propagation level

Comment: This rollbackException you mention, is it ajavax.persistence.RollbackException ? If so, it should only appear at the end of the transaction, when it is committing. Can you check the transaction status before the save method to check if it is not already marked for rollback? Or is it that the method "markReportAsFailed" is the one throwing rollbackException?

Comment: i think you should try with reportDAO.markReportAsFailed transaction with REQUIRES_NEW as you would like parent transaction as rollback butmarkReportAsFailed to be commited

Comment: @Luciano yes it is a javax.persistence.RollbackException. The outside (processPendingReport) transaction is marked as rollbackOnly, so the markReportAsFailed transaction does not complete. (that's how i understand it at least.

Comment: @JigarParekh I will try it and get back with the results.

Comment: @spyk good to hear that it has worked

Comment: Removing the @Transactional from the DAO class should also work.  Or simply make the method on the DAO class non-public (assuming they are in the same package).  The annotation only triggers a rollback for public methods.

Answer (score -1):

If a database exception (e.g. constraint violation) occurs in `reportDAO.save()` or `reportDAO.markReportAsFailed()` the transaction will be rolled back on the database level no matter what you are doing on the application level.

You can still mark the report as failed if `reportDao.save()` fails when you create a new transaction for `reportDAO.markReportAsFailed()`. Since `ReportDAO` is annotated `@Transactional` just remove the `@Transactional` annotation from the service method. You could also change the `reportDAO.save()` implementation to use a database function or stored procedure that wraps the insert statement and catches any exceptions on the database level.

HTH.

Comment: The error does not occur on the db level, but in the code. So, in the "//do processing stuff" portion, I sometimes get a NullPointerException for example, and the whole (outside) transaction gets rollbacked, which does not allow the markReportAsFailed to execute and actually change the report status.